# Show $a^2+b^2+2|ab-c|\ge 2|c|$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I saw in a paper the relation

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in\mathbb{C}$. Then
>   $$a^2+b^2+2|ab-c|\ge 2|c|,$$
>   with equality iff $a=b=0$.

There was no citation for this, and I'm not sure how to go about proving it. Does anyone know how I can prove this, or know of a reference where it is derived?

Edit: Cauchy's solution is straightforward when $|c|>|ab|$. If $|ab|>|c|$ however the reverse triangle inequality yields
$$a^2+b^2+2|ab|-2|c|\ge a^2+b^2.$$
We can then derive $a^2+b^2>2|c|$ by considering:
$$(|a|-|b|)^2\ge 0,$$
$$a^2+b^2-2|a||b|\ge 0,$$
$$a^2+b^2-2|c|\ge 0.$$

Comment: The equality case is certainly wrong.  $a=b=c=1$ is a counterexample.  However, if $c\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ is assumed, then yes, the equality condition is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) (see the next to last section), we have $|ab - c| = |c-ab| \ge |c| - |ab|$. Hence:

$$a^2 + b^2 + 2|ab-c| \ge a^2 + b^2 - 2|ab| + 2|c| = (|a|-|b|)^2 + 2|c| \ge 2|c|$$